# Python - Passing a frame containing tkinter widgets into a class

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm tring to build a scrollable GUI window containing `ttk.Entry` and `ttk.Label`.

The only way doing so (as noted in many questions here )- is by creating a `Canvas`, with a frame that contains all that widgets.

So- my goal is to make such class- that gets as a parameter a frame containing all needed widgets, and display it in a window with horizontal and vertical scroll bars ( since I need it in many displays inside my code ).

After coding successfully - I tried to make a class, but it shows only empty green canvas.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class CanvasWidgets(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, frame_in, width=100, height=100):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.master = master
        self.frame = frame_in
        self.width, self.height = width, height

        self.build_gui()

    def build_gui(self):
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.master, self.width, self.height, bg='light green')
        # self.frame = ttk.Frame(self.frame_in)

        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self.frame, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.hsb = tk.Scrollbar(self.frame, orient="horizontal", command=self.canvas.xview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set, xscrollcommand=self.hsb.set)
        self.vsb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.N + tk.S + tk.W)
        self.hsb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.W + tk.N + tk.E)
        self.canvas.create_window((4, 4), window=self.frame, anchor="nw")

        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)

    def onFrameConfigure(self, event):
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))


root = tk.Tk()
frame = ttk.Frame(root)

rows, cols = 5, 5
for row in range(rows):
    for col in range(cols):
        ttk.Label(frame, text=[row, col], relief=tk.SUNKEN, width=5).grid(row=row, column=col, sticky=tk.E)

a = CanvasWidgets(root, frame)
a.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You are making the parent the frame, not the canvas

Comment: can you specify more ?

Comment: see [ScrolledFrame](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/tkinter/scrolled-frame-canvas/scrolledframe.py) and [example with ScrolledFrame](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/tkinter/scrolled-frame-canvas/frame-example-1.py)

Comment: you need three elements `external frame` with `canvas` (inside this frame) with `internal frame` (inside canvas). Scrollbars should be in external frame but you put then in internal frame.

Comment: That what I was thinking but I did not succeed doing so

Comment: `self.frame` is internal frame, and `self` is external frame

Comment: BTW: you don't have to do `self.master = master` because `ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)` does it automatically.

Comment: @furas thank you for you link... too bad I was not familiar with it , it solves the need( bit differently ) not to do it... BUT, since I have invested quite some time- I wonder what did I do wrong. I'll appreciate your help. Brayn helped, but still it is not OK. can you please help ?

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is that you are placing the canvas in `master` when it needs to be in `self`. Think of the instance of `CanvasWindow` as a box in which you are going to put everything else.

The second problem is that, because the frame was created before the canvas, the frame has a lower stacking order than the canvas. You need to call `lift` on the frame to get it to be above the canvas.

The third problem is that you're putting the scrollbars in `frame`. You can't put them in the inner frame because they control the inner frame. Instead, they also need to be in `self`. Both the scrollbar and the canvas need to share a common parent.

The fourth problem is that the frame isn't a child of the canvas, so it won't be clipped by the borders of the canvas. It would be better if the `CanvasWidgets` created the frame, and then the caller can get the frame and add widgets to it.

For example:

```
a = CanvasWidgets(root)

rows, cols = 5, 5
for row in range(rows):
    for col in range(cols):
        label = ttk.Label(a.frame, text=[row, col], relief=tk.SUNKEN, width=5)
        label.grid(row=row, column=col, sticky=tk.E)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I did the following: 1) `self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg='light green')` ,2) `self.frame.lift()`, 3) both scrollbars changed to :`self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)` ,4)  `self.canvas.create_window((4, 4), window=self.frame, anchor="nw")`  ----> which mostly OK, but now `self.frame` hides scrollbars. how can I make scrollbar highest ?

Comment: @Guy.D `self.frame` has to use `canvas` as parent, and it can be problem.

Comment: @furas but `self.frame` if the frame containing the widgets ( which is the parameter for class)

Comment: @Guy.D `frame` which you create outside `CanvasWidgets` has to use `canvas` from `CanvasWidgets` as parent. So you should  first create `cw = CanvasWidgets(root)` , and later your frame with cavas as parent `Frame(cw.canvas)`

Comment: Thanks, @furas. I've updated my answer to include that information.